# Single State Coupled to a Continuum of States

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-optics

I have been reading a book on Quantum Optics and I have a question about a step.

Consider a system in state $\vert{i}\rangle$ at $t=0$ ($E_i = \hbar \omega_i$), and this state is coupled to a continuum of states denoted by $\vert{r}\rangle$  ($E_r = \hbar \omega_r$). Assume further that $\vert{i}\rangle$ is coupled to states $\vert{r}\rangle$ through $V(t)=-\hbar\Omega(e^{-i\omega t} + e^{i\omega t})$, where $\Omega_{ir} = \langle{i}\vert{\Omega}\vert{r}\rangle$.

The state of the system at any time $t \ge 0$ can be written as

$$
\begin{equation}
   \vert{\Psi(t)}\rangle = c_i(t) \vert{i}\rangle + \int d \omega_r \ c_r(t)  \vert{r}\rangle      
\end{equation}
$$

Using Schrodinger's equation, the authors obtain the following system

$$
\begin{equation}
    \frac{\partial}{\partial{t}}c_i = -i \omega_i c_i + i \int d \omega_r \ \Omega_{ir} e^{i\omega t} c_r
\end{equation}
$$
$$
\begin{equation}
    \frac{\partial}{\partial{t}}c_r = -i \omega_r c_r + i \Omega_{ri} e^{-i\omega t}  c_i
\end{equation}
$$

where they have adopted the RWA and kept only one of the exponentials in each of the equations above.

I understand the first of the two equations, but I cannot prove the second one. All I got was the following

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial{t}} \int{d \omega_r c_r(t)} = -i \omega_r \int{d\omega_{r} c_r(t)} + i \Omega_{ri} e^{-i\omega t} 
$$

How do i get rid of the integrals? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this derivation helps. The Schoedinger equation is
$$
\frac{d}{dt} |\psi(t)\rangle = - \frac{i}{\hbar} H |\psi(t)\rangle
$$
Using the definition of $| \psi(t) \rangle$
$$
\dot{c_i}(t) |i\rangle + \int d\omega_{r'} \dot{c}_{r'}(t) |r'\rangle = -\frac{i}{\hbar} \left[(\hbar \omega_i + V(t)) c_i(t) |i\rangle + \int d\omega_{r'} (\hbar \omega_{r'} + V(t)) c_{r'}(t) |r'\rangle \right]
$$
Applying $\langle r|$ to both sides give the correct relations by noticing
$$
\langle r | r' \rangle = \delta_{r, r'} = \delta(\omega_r - \omega_{r'})
$$
and by assuming the continuum does not self interact (the self-interaction can also be assumed to be a higher-order correction in perturbation theory) meaning
$$
\langle r | V |r' \rangle \propto \Omega_{r,r'} = 0
$$